# convert grayscale into RGB for Boson thermal camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, flir

I have bought BOSON FLIR camera and I tested with Jetson Xavier and it works by streaming with  Python & opencv. I have an issue that I am getting grayscale image while I am looking for  video with RGB color like [Ironbow color](https://www.flir.com/discover/ots/outdoor/your-perfect-palette/). This is the code that I am using with python on nvidia board

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
dispW=640
dispH=480
flip=2
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('nanoCam',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

kindly looking for your support for conversion.

Comment: Do you have an example image? Maybe have a look at colorMap functions.

Comment: ironbow seems equivalent to opencv's `COLORMAP_PLASMA` -- docs for colormap: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html -- this has nothing to do with deep learning (tag removed) and you haven't used PIL either (tag removed). if you feel that any of those tags were warranted, feel free to add them again.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# im_gray is the "WHITE HOT" picture from FLIR's web site
colorized = cv.applyColorMap(im_gray, cv.COLORMAP_PLASMA)
```

here's the result:

[image: COLORMAP_PLASMA]

compare to FLIR's Ironbow:

[image: FLIR Ironbow]

I think OpenCV's color map is somewhat comparable but it's not as saturated. If you need to match FLIR's color map, there are ways to replicate that even more faithfully.

Read all about colormaps:

- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html

FLIR pictures (white hot + ironbow) pirated from:

- https://www.flir.com/discover/ots/outdoor/your-perfect-palette/

Comment: which inputs did you use, can you refer also ?

Comment: I did say that in the code comment and I've linked to the FLIR page that contains the picture...

Comment: yeah but flir pages include many pics difficult to know which one input

Comment: that's why I said: "FLIR pictures (white hot + ironbow) pirated from:..." I believe that's clear.